# Load html using ajax get, then find specific content by tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, element

I am attempting to find a specific URL in the HTML I am loading via AJAX get.

I have attempted to use the below code but it returns undefined

```
var url_f_elem = $(html).find(".wb-bnr ~ a").html();
```

The html is below - I am attempting to acquire the url inside the a href

```
<header role="banner">
<div id="wb-bnr" class="container">
    <section id="wb-lng" class="visible-md visible-lg text-right">
    <h2 class="wb-inv">Language selection</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="list-inline margin-bottom-none">
                <li>
                    <a lang="fr" href="/fr/ministere-defense-nationale/nouvelles/2017/09/la_construction_dunnouveaubatimentamelioreralentretiendevehicule.html">
                        Français

                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `wb-bnr` is class or Id?? if id use `$(html).find("#wb-bnr ~ a").html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `wb-bnr` is the `id` of the element, not the `class`, so you should be using `#wb-bnr`.

Secondly, the `~` operator is the general sibling selector which isn't appropriate here as the `a` is not a sibling of `#wb-bnr`. You can just remove it.

Lastly, to get the URL you need to get the `href` attribute, not the text of the element. Try this:

```
var url_f_elem = $(html).find("#wb-bnr a").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$(html).find("#wb-bnr a").attr('href');
```

You dont have to to use the sibling selector.

$( "prev ~ siblings" ) is used to select all sibling elements that follow after the "prev" element, have the same parent, and match the filtering "siblings" selector. https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Sample Snippet:

```js
var url_f_elem = $('body').find("#wb-bnr a").attr('href');
console.log(url_f_elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header role="banner">
<div id="wb-bnr" class="container">
    <section id="wb-lng" class="visible-md visible-lg text-right">
    <h2 class="wb-inv">Language selection</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="list-inline margin-bottom-none">
                <li>
                    <a lang="fr" href="/fr/ministere-defense-nationale/nouvelles/2017/09/la_construction_dunnouveaubatimentamelioreralentretiendevehicule.html">
                        Français

                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: All correct answers, this was the first so I will accept this.  Thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its true.I was the last

Comment: Sorry, I guess the more recent are on the top, didn't consider...will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do that in case u need "Français" string .

```
var url_f_elem = $('#wb-bnr').find('a').html().trim();
```

i think you need to do that in case u need url attr.

```
var url_f_elem = $('#wb-bnr').find('a').attr('href');
```